# my windows os not showing when i try to create a dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

I tried to install linux in another partition with my other os being windows but when the option for installing grub appeared it said they was no  other os on my system. How do i rectify this or what  error occurred for this to happen?

Comment: Best to see details: Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Answer (score -1):

GRUB2 does not recognizes Windows Vista/7/8/10 boot loader. But you really don't need to.

Even so, you can install Ubuntu's distros without lose any data: just select the installation type option "something else" and resize the Windows partition (If you don't have enough space for Linux yet). Then, you can create the necessary partitions: a Swap partition with the same size as your RAM memory, and at least one ext4 partition to mount "/"... you can even set two partitions; one for the system (mount point "/") and one for the data (mount point "/home").

Now you can install without worrying about losing data. But once you get your Ubuntu installation you won't be able to boot Windows... don't dispair: you can fix it by using Lilo, a program that allows you to restore Windows MBR (Master Boot Record):

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lilo
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Of course, you must be sure that your physical hard drive is "/dev/sda" (if you only have one Disk, it must be this... else, you can use Disks utility to verify).

Then reboot, and you will be able to boot Windows (but only Windows). Now it's time to restore Linux boot (yes, another restore): donwload and install EasyBCD (http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/); an application to manage multiple boots. Here you can add a new entry on the boot list for Ubuntu (selecting GRUB2) and aiming to the ext4 partition where Linux is installed, and you can even decide what OS will be the default option. Don't be afraid, just make a backup of the MBR... EasyBCD allows you to. It have a very intuitive interface. You won't have any problem to use it, I hope.

It can happen, too, that some crazy future update on Ubuntu restore de GRUB2 original boot... then you won't be able to boot Windows; once again, don't dismay: this can be fixed using Lilo...

```
sudo lilo -M /dev/sda mbr
```

Abraham Medina.

Comment: i have installed lilo and entered the commands but when i tried to reboot its printing out no boot device

Comment: Are you sure that your physical drive is "/dev/sda"? I mean, are Windows and Ubuntu partitions on this hard disk?